# Which characters are used as letters inside a fulltext index of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search

I can add a fulltext index to MySQL tables. This will index all words of the related fields inside the table.

But what are "words"? Indeed they incloses letters and digits (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) and maybe the underscrore (_). But the default MyISAM stopwords contains abostrophs too. For example "can't" is a word or it.

So I would like to know, which characters are inside words of a fulltext index in MySQL / MariaDB?

Comment: Read [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) starting from "The MySQL FULLTEXT implementation" till the end of the next paragraph. Search the same in MariaDB user manual.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment is the answer!